# Quadratic Diophantine to Pell reduction

Tags: diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html says the equation $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=k$$ can be reduced to Pell equation.

Can someone explain how?

Comment: Do you know how to complete the square?

Comment: I also do not think that the article says what you claim it does. They are separate lines of though.

Comment: What do you think it says?

Comment: They are not sequential statements. There is an entire paragraph (line) between them that talks about implementation in Mathematica, and another paragraph (line) which mentions deeper results for more than 2 variables.

Comment: Well if you know the correct form of the question I am implying, please feel free to modify this question. I am a bit clueless here.

Comment: @CalvinLin Kindly see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

To sketch the how, starting with $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=k$, look at it as a quadratic in $x$.  We then need
$$x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4a(cy^2-k)}}{2a}$$
to be an integer.  Clearly this needs $\sqrt{b^2-4a(cy^2-k)} = z$ to be an integer.

So we solve  $z^2 + (4ac)y^2 = b^2 + 4ak$, which is a generalised Pell equation and I suppose you are familiar with solving.

Of course we need to (in the end) pick solutions only where $2a \mid (-b \pm z)$.

---

Another approach is to use a general translation $X = px + qy, Y = ry$ and then pick the values such that the cross term disappears, then complete the square etc...  If I recall the specific translation, will post it.  An old reference I have is http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/95/quadratics (check part 2)

Comment: Great answer. Thankyou. Actually I am unfamiliar with solving Pell as well. Could you write that portion as well?

Comment: Describing how to solve the general Pell equation is quite an elaborate job, there are methods using continued fractions, using factoring in a specific ring, algorithms for finding at least one solution etc., including cases where there are no solutions.  The good thing is I am sure you should find many references on the web.  For e.g. check http://www.ams.org/notices/200202/fea-lenstra.pdf .  Most of them boil down to "somehow" finding one solution, if this exists, then using a characteristic recurrence pattern to find infinitely many more solutions.

Comment: Can you explain on factorization in appropriate rings would produce solution of Pell equation?

Answer (score 3):

***Edit:***  This is a shorter and clearer answer to the older version.

Actually, *Mathworld* is correct when [it says solving](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation2ndPowers.html),

$$a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 = k\tag{1}$$

involves the usual *Pell equation*,

$$x^2-Dy^2 = \pm 1$$

Given an initial solution {$m,n$} to,

$$a m^2 + b mn + c n^2 = k\tag{2}$$

then we have the identity,

$$a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 - k  = k(u^2-Dv^2-1)(u^2-Dv^2+1)\tag{3}$$

where,

$$x = m u^2 - 2 (b m + 2 c n) u v + D m v^2$$

$$y = n u^2 + 2 (2 a m + b n) u v + D n v^2$$

$$D = b^2-4ac$$

for *arbitrary* variables $u,v$.  However, if one wishes to set $(3)$ equal to zero,  then $u,v$ should be chosen to satisfy the *Pell equation*,

$$u^2-Dv^2=\pm 1$$

which, for non-square discriminant $D>0$, should provide an infinite number of integer solutions for the $x,y$ of $(3)$.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks!

Comment: @CalvinLin I modified the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Do you know if this provides *all* solutions? i.e., letting $u,v$ range over all integers, do you eventually generate all integer solutions of (1)?

Comment: @KierenMacMillan: I'm not sure. Also, while $(3)$ is valid for ***any*** $u,v$, one has to choose such that $u^2-Dv^2 =\pm1$ to make $(1)$ true, hence $u,v$ does not range over all integers if the objective is $(1)$.

Comment: Of course; I meant ranging over all integer solutions to the Pell equation. As for the completeness… I smell a theorem I need to prove.  ;)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: Do you know of a formula that uses the arbitrary Pellian equation $$u^2-Dv^2=\pm t$$ (where the formula here is the special case $t=1$)?

Comment: @tito-piezas-iii What to do if $a=b=c=1$ ? It makes $D=b^2-4ac=-3<0$.

Comment: @yW0K5o I believe this implies the equation only has finitely many integer solutions (as is the case for many $a,b,c$).